# Simple forms, but input buttoms are getting the same action

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two forms in html. First form does the upload file. Second form does the authentication and import the grades to my system. However, when I click on "upload button" this input button does the upload the file and at the same time does the import. I would like to isolote the buttons behaviour. Button upload should only do the upload and the import grades only the the import.How do I separte the buttons behaviour?

```
<form  action=""  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1">
    Choose CSV File:
    <input type="file" accept="text/csv" name="userfile"/>
    <span> </span>
    <input type="submit" name="btnUpload" id="btnUpload" value="Upload"/>

    <?php
        require_once "upload.php";

    ?>             
</form>         

<br>         
<form action="authenticateUser.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="configForm">
    <input  type="submit" name="btnImport" value="Import Grades" >   

    <?php 
        require_once "apiCalls.php";  
    ?>  

</form>
```

Comment: Where is the upload form posting to? If both are pointing to `authenticateUser.php`, you can always change one of their destinations, or create a conditional there that will check the contents of the `$_POST`.

Comment: It sends to upload.php

Comment: Since you have `action=""` it uploads to the script that the form was in. If that script is `upload.php`, it makes no sense for it to contain `require_once "upload.php"` -- why would it require itself?

Comment: The scripts that receive the posts should check `if (isset($_POST['btnUpload'))` and `if (isset($_POST['btnImport']))`. If they do this, you shouldn't get multiple actions.

Comment: @barmar I added your suggestion to my code, but now when I click on import button it does no t call the apiCalls.php file. How do I fix that? ` <input  type="submit" name="btnImport" id ="btnImport" value="Import Grades" >  `       
                          ` <?php      
                           if (isset($_POST['btnImport'])){
                               require_once "apiCalls.php";
                           }      
                    }
                   ?>  `

Comment: `require_once "apiCalls.php";` is executed in the script that creates the form, not when the form is submitted. When you submit, it calls `authenticateUser.php`.

Comment: @Barmar it makes sense, but how I fix it? I tried to call authenticateUser.php outside of the form and it redirect to an invalid url. So, to the user import the file, the user need to be authenticated.

Comment: The `action` URL should be the script that performs the import.

Comment: @Barmar ok, but should I place authenticateUser.php?

Comment: I don't know what that is or how it relates to this form. I assumed from your code that it's the script that imports the data from the form.